# vb.net passing string into button click sub

Tags: vb.net, string, oop

There are 2 forms, the first one contains labeled buttons and when all use the same form but as a "dim form2 as new form. the second form the uses a select case to determine which buttons to draw and title ect. the part I'm struggling with, is the new buttons I have created i need to get there separate names into the event handler sub.

so when i click the new created buttons they all do the same process i need a way of separating them in the "button operation sub"

```
Public Class DiaryAddForms

Private Sub DiaryAddForms_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 

End Sub


' gets the selected case from the button pushed on diary, then draws the appropreate buttons labels ect to the form//

Public Sub GetFormType(ByVal Type As String)

    Select Case Type

        Case "add"

            ' changes the text of the form to the button clicked,
            Me.Text = ("Add Appointment")


            ' passes the appropreate data for the buttons required for add appointment to the "button" sub''

            Button(x:=180, y:=200, name:="Cfind_Btn", title:="Find", hieght:=30, width:=50)
            Button(x:=235, y:=200, name:="Cnew_Btn", title:="New", hieght:=30, width:=50)


        Case "edit"
            Me.Text = ("Edit Appointment")

        Case "delete"
            Me.Text = ("Delete Appointment")

        Case "endday"
            Me.Text = ("End Day")

    End Select

End Sub

' rather than have to create each button individual the data types of each different button can be passed into this sub and then created. 

Public Sub Button(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal name As String, ByVal title As String, ByVal hieght As Integer, ByVal width As Integer)
    Dim btn As Button
    btn = New Button

    With btn
        .Location = New Point(x, y)
        .Text = title
        .Name = name
        .Width = width
        .Height = hieght
        Controls.Add(btn)

    End With

    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf BtnOperation
End Sub

Public Sub BtnOperation(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'i need a way to fetch the btn.name'
    'so then with the name use "select case" to get appropreate action of the btn. ' 



End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Cast `sender` to a `Button` instance. In C# you could use `((Button)sender).Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `BtnOperation`, the `sender` parameter will be your button, so you can just cast it and access the `Name` property.

```
Public Sub BtnOperation(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim name As String = btn.Name
    ' do whatever
End Sub
```